# Can I practice automation testing on Gmail?

Tags: selenium, c#-4.0, gmail

Am I allowed to run some tests I created on Gmail or are there any policies against this? This is purely for practice.

Comment: The Gmail api and smtp servers are open.  Assuming that you set up authentication you can of do what ever you want with them.   However i would recommend not using your main gmail account if you spam the server google wills shut you down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your Question straight **`Yes`** you can practice automation testing on Gmail.

Having said that there are certain `Caveat` mentioned in the `Google Terms of Service`. The most important of them being the first one as:

> Don’t misuse our Services. For example, don’t interfere with our
>   Services or try to access them using a method other than the interface
>   and the instructions that we provide. You may use our Services only as
>   permitted by law, including applicable export and re-export control
>   laws and regulations. We may suspend or stop providing our Services to
>   you if you do not comply with our terms or policies or if we are
>   investigating suspected misconduct.

Its worth to mention that Google extensively uses cookies and finger prints (to name a few) to identify an user. Somehow if your IP gets black-listed it will be tough task to regain back the access.